# The usage of block grid and reason of its existence in Foundation5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I recently found Foundation5 has [Block Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) which has rarely found use case online anywhere to demostrate the importance of using it... or is it even a great function to have? Because I am currently using Bootstrap3 and found it does not have Block Grid. So I wonder if its really a big feature one should watch out for.
Maybe some critical user case that will be so much better to use Block Grid other than Column based Grid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several differences between the `block grid` and regular column `grid`..

- The block grid is always evenly spaced and distributed
- The block grid requires less markup
- The block grid doesn't have inner padding

Take a look at this demo: http://codeply.com/go/XiyFxtMcXT, and you'll see the differences. Notice how the `block-grid` evenly wraps the items when the items exceed one row.

Answer (score 0):

Block grids give you a way to evenly split contents of a list within the grid. If you wanted to create a row of five images or paragraphs that need to stay evenly spaced no matter the screen size, the block grid is for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just as easily use a percentage based grid system to achieve the same result.

I think the benefit of the 'block grid' is:

1. Items are displayed in a 'ul' which will group them together (good, for accessibility).
2. It's quicker to add one style to a 'ul' that will automatically make each 'li' a 'column' than it is to add "col-x" to each 'li' manually
3. They've already built it so you don't need to.